# Passing array to function returns "Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

Tags: vba, excel

I have following subroutine which prints the array elements:

```
Sub printArray(arr() As Variant)
  Dim i, lowerBound, upperBound As Integer
  lowerBound = LBound(arr)
  upperBound = UBound(arr)

  MsgBox "lowerBound: " & lowerBound
  MsgBox "upperBound: " & upperBound

  For i = lowerBound To upperBound
    MsgBox i & " : " & arr(i)
  Next i
End Sub
```

This is working as expected and I'm calling it in the following way:

```
Sub callPrintArray()
  Dim arr(3) As Variant
  arr(0) = "John"
  arr(1) = "Star"
  arr(2) = #6/30/2010# ' Hire Date

  ' PRINTS ONE EXTRA ELEMENT WITHOUT THIS LINE
  ' Dim arr(3) As Variant MEANS INDEXING FROM 0 TO 2
  arr(3) = "LAST"
  Call printArray(arr)
End Sub
```

Then I have function which return existing sheets as array:

```
Function getListOfSheetsW() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim sheetNames() As Variant

  ReDim sheetNames(1 To Sheets.Count)
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    sheetNames(i) = Sheets(i).Name
  Next i

  getListOfSheetsW = sheetNames
End Function
```

I want to print the sheets returned by this function with mentioned subroutine `printArray`. I've tried:

```
Sub callGetListOfSheetsW()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = getListOfSheetsW()

    ' Working
    MsgBox arr(1)
    MsgBox arr(2)

    ' Does not working
    ' Call printArray(arr)
End Sub
```

When I print particular element it is working, but when I want to print whole array using `printArray` it is not and I get:

> Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @pnuts can you please explain how did you make `Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected.` message appear in yellow box? Thank you.

Comment: Note that when writing `Dim i, lowerBound, upperBound As Integer`, only upperBound is defined as Integer, i and lowerBound are really of Type Variant. You need to use `As Interger` for each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Variant (which may happen to contain an array) is not the same as an array of Variants. You need to change this line:

```
Dim arr As Variant
```

to this:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. So `Dim arr As Variant` was array containing Variant and `Dim arr() As Variant` is array of variants? Am I right?

Comment: Not quite: `Dim arr As Variant` is a `Variant` that happens to contain an array.